# ¿Cómo usar funciones propias de MariaDB/MySQL en PDO mediante bindValue o bindParam en una cláusula INSERT?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

Estoy usando PDO para gestionar una tabla y necesito ejecutar un par de funciones de MySQL/MariaDB (concretamente `CONVERT(CAST(TextoFichero as BINARY) USING utf8)`) sobre un campo antes de realizar la inserción del dato en cada registro.

En el hilo inglés https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067782/php-pdo-insert-current-date-plus-one-month-into-mysql plantean el mismo problema y el único que respondió, dio una respuesta incorrecta (no funciona, inserta el literal, no ejecuta la función) pero como no tengo "reputación" suficiente, no se lo puedo comunicar.

Por más que busco ejemplos concretos de referencia, no encuentro ninguno que muestre algo asi ¿no es posible usar algo tan sencillo como la función "`now()`" o "`current_date()`" usando PDO en un INSERT? Ojo, que no busco alternativas en PHP para crear previamente los valores e insertarlos, sino trasladar a MySQL las funciones tal y como lo haría en una sentencia SQL sin usar PDO.

Gracias

**Actualización**: Ejemplo real tras la solución del usuario ciberelfo:

```
foreach ($V_Registros as $V_Registro)
{
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `Documentos_OCR` (`NombreFichero`, `Kbytes`, `Fecha`,  `Texto_OCR`) 
         VALUES (:NombreFichero, :Kbytes, CURRENT_DATE(), CONVERT(CAST('{$V_Registro[0]}' as BINARY) USING utf8)    )");
    try
    { // $dbh->quote(file_get_contents($V_Registro[4]))])
        $stmt->execute([':NombreFichero' => $V_Registro[0], ':Kbytes' => $V_Registro[1]]);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        exit($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Nota: Importantísimo poner entre apóstrofes (comillas simples) las variables de nuestro código PHP que vayamos a usar en "prepare()", porque si no lo hacemos, el motor de la bb.dd. lo interpretará como un número de columna.

Comment: Hola, por favor pulsa en [edit] para agregar el código y los eventuales mensajes de error que estás recibiendo.

Comment: Hola Rafael, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. ¿Que has intentado? ¿Podrías compartir tu código? Utiliza la opción [edit] para agregar esta info en tu pregunta.

Comment: Marcos, yo había intentado lo que viene en el enlace (en inglés) al que hice referencia, que NO funcionaba y me hizo perder muchísimo tiempo. Ciberelfo ha acertado perfectamente con la respuesta, así que muchas gracias. He añadido cómo quedaría el código, por si a alguien le sirve de referencia.

Comment: A. Cedano, como le he comentado a Marcos, el problema era que la solución del enlace al que hacía referencia, no trasladaba a la bb.dd. la función para que la ejecutase, sino que la mandaba como literal y así se incorporaba al campo correspondiente de la bb.dd. No había errores que mostrar, porque simplemente no hacía lo que la supuesta solución decía.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si vas a insertar una función de mysql directamente no es necesario que hagas el bind value, puedes hacer algo como:

```
INSERT INTO patata_database (patata_id, temp_patata, text) 
VALUES(:patata_id, :temp_patata, CONVERT(CAST(TextoFichero as BINARY) USING utf8) )
```

Comment: PER-FEC-TO. Funciona perfectamente. Ni se me había ocurrido - pero tiene su lógica - hacerlo así. Me has alegrado el día. Comento para quien llegue aquí que hay que eliminar el posicionador que corresponda en la llamada a "execute()" (o de los "bindValue") porque si no, PHP no dirá que sobra un parámetro (que hemos puesto explícitamente en "VALUES" del "INSERT INTO".
P.D.: ¿Podría alguien con "reputación" suficiente marcar como INVÁLIDA la respuesta en inglés de la que puse el enlace? Muchísimos - como yo - habrán estado perdiendo el tiempo intentando que esa solución funcionase.